# Is possible to use an expression logic on @Formula which has a boolean field to compare dates?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to know if the following example works with `@Formula` of hibernate, perhaps someone can help to solve the other ways, to use sql or queries.

```
@Formula("SELECT( NOW() > column_date - interval '1 minute' * column_a )")
private Boolean columnA;
```

When I do that example get the following error:

> 2019-03-03 05:29:57.568 ERROR [service_a,4fedd46e4085e86f,4fedd46e4085e86f,false] 608 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: schema "table_a0_" does not exist   Position: 5560
>
> 2019-03-03 05:29:57.581  INFO [service_a,4fedd46e4085e86f,4fedd46e4085e86f,false] 608 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : HHH000327: Error performing load command :

what is it wrong on my sql expression?

Comment: just to cross it of the list have you double checked the name of your schema as your error says it doesn't exists? also have you looked at the query in hibernate log to see if everything is correct?

Comment: I wanna know if my expression logic which is boolean, is it fine? or What I need to add or update .....

Comment: Thanks @GMB for editing the question!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a proper SQL query in `@Formula`, something like:

```
@Formula("select NOW() > ( column_date + interval '1 minute' * column_a ) from some_table")
```

Of course assuming your dbms reads this syntax. `some_table` is a table, where `column_date` and `column_a` are.

The easiest would be to run SQL queries against your database and insert it into `@Formula` when successful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm in my entity , why should I add my table? @Andronicus

Comment: Did you read the first sentence of my answer? "There should be a proper SQL query in `@Formula`". This means, that whatever there is in `@Formula`, should be able to run successfully against database.